# After loadHTMLString the uiwebview freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, timeout, connection

I have a local HTML file which I'm using `WKWebView` to load on my viewController. After the site appear inside the app, every functionality on the site, for example a slider, freezes the entire app. And only this message is appearing:

> Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply

my code:

```
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FlowPage" ofType:@"html"]];
        NSString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

        WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
        WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
        [wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

        WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;

        _wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:wkWebConfig];
        _wkWebView.UIDelegate = self;
        _wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
        _wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _wkWebView.clipsToBounds = YES;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_wkWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.icarros.com.br"]];
        });

        [self.view addSubview:_wkWebView];
```

Appear's that the site is show as my local archive but all interaction or process of data needed is lost in the middle. He can't execute nothing on the server side.

Comment: Can you show the snippet how you rendering to WKWebkit ?

Comment: @satishiOS25 i've edited my question.